# How to add the java variable value in the Configuration util String -

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, eclipse

I am writing Java code for calling ROR APIs ..

I have written Java code to get all the blogs by

```
    public List<BlogBean> getBlogsXml() {

     return webResource.path(ConfigurationUtil.LIST_BLOGS).header(ConfigurationUtil.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, authentication)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<BlogBean>>() {
 });
  }
```

where in my Configuration.Utilfile
 LIST_BLOGS will be http://localhost:3000/api/blogs.xml

now I trying to fetch the blogs that matches a field value for the blogs 
My blogs table contains a field slug so that those keyword that matches this will be returned. For this I received the input slug and now I need to append this slug with my path in the ConfigurationUTIL file
 LIST_BLOGS_SLUG = "http://localhost:3000/api/blogs/.xml"

how should I do this.. Below is my code for receiving the slug parameter

```
public List<BlogBean> showBlog_slug(String slug)
{
  return webResource.path(ConfigurationUtil.LIST_BLOGS_SLUG).header(ConfigurationUtil.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, authentication)
  .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<BlogBean>>() {
  });
}
```

Comment: I have moved your solution to a community answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I have found the solution by keeping the string in the method

```
public List<BlogBean> showBlog_slug(String slug){
  final string LIST_BLOGS_SLUG="mypath/api/blogs/"+slug+".xml"
     return webResource.path(LIST_BLOGS_SLUG).header(ConfigurationUtil.AUTHENTICATION_HEADER, authentication)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).get(new GenericType<List<BlogBean>>() {
  });
}
```